# asp.net mvc period in POST parameter

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-2

i konw that you can have a period in a querystring parameter, but you cant specify a period in variable names in .net.

The following code obviously does not work, but my external system uses the period in the names.  Is there a way to do this?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(string hub.mode)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read the value directly from the `Request` hash:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string hubMode = Request["hub.mode"];
    return View();
}
```

or using an intermediary class:

```
public class Hub
{
    public string Mode { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Hub hub)
{
    string hubMode = hub.Mode;
    return View();
}
```

As you will notice `.` has special meaning for the ASP.NET MVC default model binder.

Comment: Is this the only way?  Seems like a parameter of hub_Mode should work as well using the underscore to replace the period. I realize that could lead to a duplicate postback, but I'd welcome an exception if someone actually had Hub.Mode and Hum_Mode defined together. I guess another way would be to make a ViewModel with a property HubMode that reads and writes to Hub.Mode.